# Setting up DNS records with Google Compute Instance

Tags: dns, google-compute-engine

We are transferring a site from Rackspace to Google Compute. I have the instance I need and have been working with it. I want to set up the DNS zone and records in Google ahead of the actual move if possible as we have many CNAME records for dynamic sub-domains that I will need to key in (I've looked into automating the DNS record transfer but it does not transfer the sub-domain records). What records can I set up ahead of time?

Thank you,
Sally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up DNS records in the GCP zone ahead of time, so long as they will not conflict with your existing records. Otherwise, it may be best to wait and do the full zone file migration, i.e., pick a time and do it all at once, and exactly copy your current records over. Please take a look at this GCP documentation regarding migration to Cloud DNS [1] that describes how to complete the necessary steps: creating a managed zone for your domain, importing your existing DNS configuration, and updating your registrar's name service records. Also, this document [2] provides a simple example of creating a managed zone, and then setting up Address (A) and Canonical Name (CNAME) records for the domain. As for subdomains, it would really depend on if they are resident in the main zone or not. If not, then you would also need to migrate the subdomain zones as well (in the same process). Hope this helps.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/migrating
[2] https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart